# Is "work offline" not supported in containers?

Tags: firefox

Firefox has a "work offline" functionality which makes it loads pages from the cache. This is sometimes useful to me.

It seems to work in normal tabs, but when using multi-account containers extension, the container tabs seem to not be able to load the same website (which I have previously visited in the container)

Does "work offline" not work with containers?